# Math.Pi constant is wrong

Tags: .net, math

I'm well aware that a Double has only so many bits of precision, but we should still try to achieve high accuracy if possible. So I certainly do not expect to see this in the official .NET 4 system library.

```
// Summary:
//     Represents the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter,
//     specified by the constant, π.
public const double PI = 3.14159;
```

Why only 6 digits? It would be easy and **free** to use an accurate value. I'm not doing scientific work in .NET, but I'm sure others do and they are in for a surprise when Pi is inaccurate. Same goes for E.

**Edit:** This tuned out to be about reflection of constants in Visual Studio. See  [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742753/are-double-constants-truncated-for-display-in-vs)

Comment: Isn't there some legal stuff in some place in the US which states that Pi = 3 ?

Comment: PI can't be either "wrong" or "right". What is right? 50 digits? 5000? 5 billion? (I totally agree that it should've more digits in a standard library)

Comment: @Alexandre C.: :=) That's only in indiana (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill)

Comment: @Alexandre C.: No. Because that would be equal parts retarded and insane.

Comment: I've just looked at mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0 in reflector and it is `public const double PI = 3.1415926535897931;` there.

Comment: Where did you get this number? Looking at mscorlib for .NET 4 it says `public const double PI = 3.1415926535897931;` - so nothing changed from version 2 to 4.

Comment: -1: As others have stated this question is completely wrong. You can even see it in the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi.aspx

Comment: Syntactically, your use of accuracy/accurate/inaccurate is correct. Semantically, you meant precision/precise/imprecise though.

Comment: @blizpasta No, I intentionally used the terms exactly how they stand there.

Comment: @mpeterson Yea, but I do not trust the documentation when the code (or what appears to be the code) says otherwise.

Comment: Not sure why mafutrct is getting slammed on this question so much.  It is a good lesson to learn, and a legitimate question to ask, even if he was a bit misdirected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Copy and pasted from Math.cs in the .NET 4.0 Reference Source:

```
  public const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
  public const double E  = 2.7182818284590452354;
```

No idea what you are looking at.

It was reverse-engineered from a follow-up question that you looked at the auto-generated text that was created from the assembly metadata when you use the Go To Definition context menu item.  Yes, the code that generates this text appears to use the default %f formatting on public double constant values.  Quite rare btw, there are *not* a lot of public constants that are double in the .NET framework.  You can file a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Interesting, when I use reflector it shows `Math.PI = 3.1415926535897931` which is different from the source (less digits and last digit should be 2).

Comment: Yet another way the double was converted to a string.  Double has only enough precision to reliably produce 15 significant digits.  Log10(2^53) = 15.95 to be exact. So any digit beyond the 16th is inevitably going to be random noise.

Comment: Probably, but for both `Math.PI` and `Math.E` the last digit is `1` instead of `2`. I mean `2.7182818284590452 3536.. = "2.7182818284590451"` and `3.1415926535897932 3846..="3.1415926535897931"`. I wonder if it is a coincidence.

Comment: Trying to find a pattern in random numbers is a pointless exercise.

Answer (score 4):

A quick test shows that `Console.WriteLine(Math.PI)` outputs `3.14159265358979` so how can this be true? Are you saying `ToString()` adds extra digits by magic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pi = Math.acos(-1)`.

More seriously, do not do math in .NET unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: @delnan: seriously .NET really lacks good math libraries. You end up reinventing the wheel often and floating point oddities are no longer the sole concern.