# Are Double constants truncated for display in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, metadata

The constant `Math.Pi` is, according to reflector and MSDN, equal to 3.14159265358979323846. When looking at the Math class in Visual Studio 2010, the value is displayed as 3.14159. Whom can I blame for truncating precious constants?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/3742692/38206

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why the OP isn't posting this, as it would clear things up so incredibly much, but you can reproduce as follows:

- Open the IDE
- Enter Math.PI into a .cs file.
- Right-click on Math.PI and click on 'Go To Definition'

This opens up the Metadata file for Math, which contains the following:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Represents the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter, specified
    //     by the constant, π.
    public const double PI = 3.14159;
```

Comment: Apparently Resharper provides better metadata view than VS, cause it gives the same value as Reflector. However, if I disable Resharper I get the result you describe. Odd.

Comment: Yup, has to be it.  This text is auto-generated from the metadata.  And clearly doesn't bother converting public constants of type double to a string with all 15 significant digits.  It is the default formatting behavior of the printf() function in C/C++ with the %f format type specifier.  It is very likely that this code was written in C++ since the metadata enumeration interface is COM based.

Comment: Thanks Hans, That is quite interesting!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to repeat myself, but how do you get that number? If I hover over the constant or print it in the Immediate or Watch window in VS2010, I get 3.1415926535897931, which is also the value I get when looking at mscorlib in Reflector.

While it is less precision than MSDN claims, it is still far better than the number you're talking about. VS has to pick a formatting for printing floating point numbers. With the results I see I find the default quite acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can blame the VS metadata view, which is what you get when you press F12 on something you don't have the source to.

At least I presume that's what you're doing, because it's the only place I can find the truncated constant you're talking about.

Why does it do it / where does it get that value from? Who knows...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a plugin for VS 2010 that is changing the output of the number.  Or maybe you're displaying the number in a display context that has to truncate the number to fit.  *Where* exactly in Visual Studio are you viewing this number?