# I understand that Sin and Cos are in radians, but why I am still off by 90 degrees?

Tags: c#, vector, trigonometry

Let's say I have the values X = 0, Y = 0 and I want to calculate a new point (X1, Y1) from a vector and a magnitude. Let's say the vector is 90 degrees (not radians) and the magnitude is 10 so the code would look something like this:

```
x1 = X + (10 * Math.Cos(90 * (Math.PI / 180.0)));
y1 = Y + (10 * Math.Sin(90 * (Math.PI / 180.0)));
```

And I then draw a line to confirm the results

```
DrawLine(X,Y,x1,y1);
```

But my line is off by 90 degrees too much! If I subtract 90 from the angle that I'm passing to Cos and Sin everything works out fine. So, I guess, I can live with that.

Here's a screen shot:
[image]

I'm passing it 90 and I'm expecting the line to go west - east. I assume that 0 degrees is due north. I know that the coordinate system I'm using is X is horizontal and Y is vertical.

I'm just curious as to what I'm missing.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What direction does your vector point (use north/south/east/west so we can imagine it too) and what direction did you expect it to point?

Comment: Perhaps you can show a screenshot of what it looks like and what you expect it to look like

Comment: How are you measuring the angles?  The trig functions expect that theta=0 corresponds to the +X axis (East), with theta increasing in the counter-clockwise direction.  For compass headings, theta=0 corresponds to due north, and increases clockwise.

Comment: Why not post some screen shot to make it clearer? Your `drawn line` would be a `vertical line` with length of `10`.

Comment: I just noticed that theta=0 corresponds to the +X axis... I'm expecting 0 to correspond to the Y axis!

Comment: What API do you use for the `DrawLine(`, could it be that it works with Rows and Columns?  (y,x) If seen that with some image processing libraries.

Comment: DrawLine is just pseudo code. I wrote something else. No, the problem is that I was expecting 0 to be on the Y axis; it's on the X axis, apparently. I know I've used cos and sin before (in C++). Is this different in C#?

Comment: I think the line starts at the purple small line? Then these results are correct. 0 Degrees are on the x-axis. Because 90 degrees => x=0, y=1.  0 degrees = x=1, y=0

Comment: @zetar it may be caused by something wrong with your implementation of `DrawLine`, you can check the **actual values** of `X` and `Y` via debugging instead of by looking at the drawn line.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen No, the line is `yellow`.

Comment: So the problem is that it's not a strait line:

Answer (score 2):

**Unexpected integer truncation**

The conversion from degrees to radians resulted in a value *near* pi/2, but not exactly.  (Hard to do as pi is transcendental.)  `Math.Cos(near_pi/2)` resulted in a value *near* 0.0, but not _exactly 0.0.  Let's assume it was negative like -6.1e-17.

Assuming 'X' was a floating point number with an integer value, the result of `X + small_negative_number` was a number *just* less than the integer value.  Assigning that result to `x1` and giving it to the `plot()` routine, which certainly uses integer values caused a *integer truncation* down to the next lower integer.

Thus the expected straight line is 1 pixel off.

The general solution is to present `plot(x,y)` with integer values that are derived from *rounded* floating point values.

```
x_int = round(X_floating_point);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem about the x and y.

```
You use COS for x.  COS(0) = 1    ,  COS(90) = 0
You use SIN for y.  SIN(0) = 0    ,  SIN(90) = 1
```

And for the screen coordinate system:

```
x+ is left to right
y+ is top to bottom
```

Thats why the line goes from top to bottom.

As you can see, the line isn't nice and straight. Follow the declaration of Math.PI and you will see: `public const double PI = 3.14159` *(I don't know whois responsible for this, but I would fire him)*. That isn't very accurate! Try to replace the PI with: `3.14159265358979323846`

Makes:

```
public const double BETTER_PI = 3,14159265358979323846

x1 = X + (10 * Math.Cos(90 * (BETTER_PI / 180.0)));
y1 = Y + (10 * Math.Sin(90 * (BETTER_PI / 180.0)));
```

So:

```
x1 = X + (10 * Math.Cos(1.57079632679)) = X + (10 * 0) = X + 0;
y1 = Y + (10 * Math.Sin(1.57079632679)) = Y + (10 * 1) = Y + 10;
```

UPDATE:

As Chis says, the meta data is wrong. So use the `Math.PI`

Comment: `Math.PI` (as in [`System.Math.PI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi.aspx)) is defined as `3.14159265358979323846`. If you're looking at the assembly metadata, it's [misreporting the value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742710/1269654). You should be fine using `Math.PI` for almost any usage.